# Transaction completion not deterministic

Tags: spring-integration

My flow setup looks like this:

```
<int:channel id="channel1">
    <int:queue/>
</int:channel>
<int:channel id="channel2">
    <int:queue/>
</int:channel>

<int:chain id="chain1" input-channel="channel1" output-channel="channel2">
    <int:poller>
        <int:transactional propagation="REQUIRES_NEW"/>
    </int:poller>
    <Authorzier/>
    <JMS_put1/>
    <DB_update_state1/>
</int:chain>

<int:chain id="chain2" input-channel="channel2" output-channel="nullChannel">
    <int:poller>
        <int:transactional propagation="REQUIRES_NEW"/>
    </int:poller>
    <Transformer/>
    <JMS_put2/>
    <DB_update_state2/>
</int:chain>
```

Now in some cases the the transaction of chain2 completes before the transaction of chain1 and I have DB_state_1 in the database.

How can I force the transaction of chain1 to complete before the message is sent to the `output-channel` of chain1?

I know I can use a `TransactionSynchronization` that sends the message to channel2 in `afterCommit()` but I assume there must be a more elegant solution.

`EDIT CURRENT WORKAROUND`

```
@ServiceActivator
public void sendToDestinationFlow(Message<?> message) {
    TxSenderSyncer s = new TxSenderSyncer(message, this.channel, this.errorChannel);
    TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(s);
}

private static class TxSenderSyncer implements TransactionSynchronization {

    private Message<?> message;
    private MessageChannel channel;
    private MessageChannel errorChannel;

    public TxSenderSyncer(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel, MessageChannel errorChannel) {
        this.message = message;
        this.channel = channel;
        this.errorChannel = errorChannel;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(int paramInt) {
        if (paramInt == STATUS_ROLLED_BACK) {
            errorChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(new MessagingException(message, "Transaction rolled back")).build());
        } else {
            channel.send(message);
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem that you have two queues, which are processed on their own poller threads.

Therefore message can be send to the second and processed there even before the end of the work in thread of the first chain.

Consider to use `<request-handler-advice-chain>` with `<tx:advice>` for that `<DB_update_state1/>` instead. In this case only DB update will be wrapped to TX. The send to the `output-channel` is caused after the finish of work on the `handleRequestMessage`: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#message-handler-advice-chain

**EDIT**

We did some investigation, and that looks like you don't have so much choice if your `QueueChannel` isn't based on the transactional `MessageStore`. In that case you should just be sure that "poll" part of that TX `QueueChannel` is in mode `READ_COMMITED`, where the "send" part is withing TX boundaries as well. And even we send message to that queue before TX commit it won't be available for polling until real commit. But, yeah, it works only for transactional `MessageStore` like `JdbcChannelMessageStore`.

If you don't use such that, you shouldn't extend transaction boundaries broader than TX resources.

To wrap those your JMS and DB services to the same transaction we propose the config like this:

```
<service-activator ref="txGateway" input-channel="channel1" output-channel="channel2">
    <poller/>
    <request-handler-advice-chain>
        <tx:advice/>
    </request-handler-advice-chain>
</service-activator>

<gateway id="txGateway" default-request-channel="txChain"/>

<chain input-channel="txChain">
    <Authorzier/>
    <JMS_put1/>
    <DB_update_state1/>
</chain>
```

Comment: I've edited my example. Usually a chain with a poller which represents a transaction has other handlers of which some are also transactional resources. So I need an overall transaction for the chain that completes before the message is sent to the `output-channel` of the chain.

Comment: Please, look into the `EDIT` in my answer.

Comment: This solution works but we have another issue [see this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39097422/dataaccessexception-not-wrapped-in-messagingexception). Currently we are using the workaround inserted in the question under `EDIT CURRENT WORKAROUND` and would appreciate your opinion on it.