# DataAccessException not wrapped in MessagingException

Tags: spring-integration

This is a follow up question to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39042219/transaction-completion-not-deterministic)

The flow looks like this:

```
<int:channel id="myapp.input">
    <int:queue/>
</int:channel>
<int:channel id="myapp.output">
    <int:queue/>
</int:channel>

<int:chain input-channel="myapp.input" output-channel="myapp.output">
    <int:poller error-channel="baseFlow.error">
        <int:transactional/>
    </int:poller>
    <int:service-activator ref="jmsService1"/>
    <int:service-activator ref="dbService2"/>
    <int:service-activator ref="jmsService2"/>
    <int:service-activator ref="dbService2"/>
</int:chain>
```

Now at the end of the chain and before sending of message to the `output-channel` 'myapp.output' the transaction is comitted and a `DataAccessException` is thrown.

The desired behavior is that in my `errorChannel` I get a `MessagingException` containing the `failedMessage` and the `DataAccessException`.

The actual behavior is that I get the bare `DataAccessException` in my `errorChannel` but I do not know which message for and I cannot react on it.

Is there a way to achieve the desired behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting - that's the normal behavior for a gateway.

Normally, gateways are used to invoke an integration flow from java code and the messaging exception is unwrapped so the caller gets the actual exception.

When a gateway is used in this context (called from some other messaging component), however, I can see that the gateway should re-throw the `MessagingException`. We will look into doing that automatically.

In the meantime...

The default `service-interface` is `RequestReplyExchanger`.

If you create your own version of `RequestReplyExchanger` and add `throws MessagingException` to the `exchange()` method, and use it in your gateway, the gateway should re-throw that exception rather than unwrapping it.

I opened a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4100).

**EDIT**

You can use nested gateways to solve the issue; remove the transaction and error channel from the poller and, instead, start the transaction at the second gateway; when the commit fails, the messaging exception will be sent to the first channel's error channel...

```
public interface TxGateway {

    @Transactional
    Message<?> exchange(Message<?> message);

}

<tx:annotation-driven/>

<int:service-activator ref="errorHandlingGW" input-channel="one">
    <int:poller ... />
</int:service-activator>

<int:gateway id="errorHandlingGW" default-request-channel="two" error-channel="two" />

<int:service-activator ref="transactionalGW" input-channel="two" />

<int:gateway id="transactionalGW" service-interface="my.TxGateway" default-request-channel="chain1" />
```

Comment: I've edited the example code. This behavior is not related to the `gateway` but is the general behavior for all exceptions thrown by the `TransactionIntercepter` - they are not wrapped in a `MessagingException` together with the `failedMessage`

Comment: Sorry; I missed the bit about the exception being thrown by the transaction advice; which knows nothing about the messaging infrastructure. You'll need to add another "around advice" in the chain before the tx advice, to wrap the exception. Another [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4101) - contributions are welcome.

Comment: I havent figured out how to do that but we are evaluating the solution documented in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39042219/transaction-completion-not-deterministic) under `EDIT CURRENT WORKAROUND`. If you could comment on this it would help to decide on the way to go

Comment: It's not clear to me where that service is invoked; it can't go at the beginning of the chain because it returns void; if it returned the message, then the message going to the error channel wouldn't be the one that failed; it would be the one entering the chain. If it's at the end of the chain, it won't be invoked if there's an exception earlier in the chain - i.e. only if the commit fails.

Comment: All correct, it's invoked as the last element of a chain. If there is an exception earlier in the chain it will be wrapped in a `MessagingException` and delivered to the `errorChannel`as required. The `TransactionInterceptor`only comes into play at the end of the chain so it's fine to have it as the last handler. Plus it needs to return null, otherwise the message is duplicated

Comment: In that case I would remove the `output-channel` from the chain to make it clear it doesn't return a message. The approach looks reasonable if you don't mind getting involved at that level. The gateway/advice mechanism would avoid getting involved with tx sync and message routing. Aside from that, I don't see any compelling reason not to go that route. I would use `new ErrorMessage(...)` rather than the message builder, just for consistency.

Comment: Actually, my thoughts about using another advice won't work - we simply don't have access to the message at that point in the call stack.

Comment: So the `TransactionSynchronization` approach seems the only way not to loose a message on rollbacks initiated by the TX advice. Please confirm. I do understand the technical background but this is a major bug and I will raise it in JIRA. A message that fails processing should always be delivered to the specified `error-channel`with both, the failure reason and the failed message

Comment: The problem is the transaction has to start before the message exists - the channel might be transactional (backed by JMS or JDBC) so pulling the message from the channel has to be part of the transaction. See my edit for an alternative to your solution.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will evaluate the different approaches and possibly come back with another follow up question in a new post. I assume opening a JIRA will result in `works as designed`?

Comment: As I said in my answer/comments, I already opened two JIRA issues INT-4100, and 4101. The second one is going to be tricky because, by necessity, the transaction has to start before the message is created, so there are no guarantees of a solution. We would need some option to apply the advice chain to just the downstream flow instead of the whole polling operation.

Comment: FYI, the approach is not working for us since we use a `Resequencer` downstream and the `gateway` relies on a reply. A timeout in this area is not affordable for us and an exception provoked by `requires-reply` also does not help